# Couldn't find User without an ID (Devise user model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I have a Devise user model. I am trying to get an input from user and compare it with a string and redirect to another page if same. But there is some problem with @user. It will be a simple problem but I am stuck for hours. Please help.

questions_controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def qn1
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
end

def submit
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user])
  if @user.answer == 'blank'
    render root_path
  else
    render 'qn1'
  end
end
end
```

qn1.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => {:controller => "questions", :action => "submit"}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :answer %>
  <%= f.text_field :answer %>

  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem? What happens? What you expect to happens?

Comment: user enters a string in the form (in answer field). Then I have to compare this answer with a predefined string in the controller and render some page if those are same else render the current form again. But the error shows that @user is nil in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve a param sent by a `form_for` using it's multidimensional array, like this:

```
params[:user][:attribute]
```

You told us that you have Devise installed and running. If you're logged in, the most easy and secure way to access the current user is with the following method (automatically provided by devise on login)

```
current_user
```

So, if you want to compare the answer sent with the current user one, you could do something like this:

```
# QuestionsController
def submit
  if current_user.answer == params[:user][:answer]
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'qn1'
  end
end
```

Or, if it is just a matter of compare the answer sent with some arbitrary string, you don't even need the User model:

```
# QuestionsController
def submit
  if params[:user][:answer] == 'blank'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'qn1'
  end
end
```

You shouldn't retrieve a user, or instantiate a new one, just to set it's answer to the one sent by the form and compare it with a string. It's absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: I thought it was just `current_user`, and not `@current_user`?

Comment: Thanks. So if the user is logged in there is no need to find the user in the method 'qn1' right? or should i give @user = current_user   ?

Comment: Now that worked.Its different error now. "No route matches {:action=>"submit", :controller=>"questions"}". When the user clicks the post button the answer must be compared with predefined string and render a page. This is done in submit method. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: @vishnu You don't have to use `@user = current_user`. Just using `current_user` in the controller or the view will do the trick. If you 're getting the 'No route matches' error, you should take a look at your **routes.rb** file to see if the route has been set. If not, you should put the route there.

Comment: When user clicks submit button it must be routed to "submit" method inside questions controller and compare the answer. Is my form_for correct to do that?

Comment: The form_for looks correct. You should see if the route exists using `rake routes` from the command line. Check the HTTP verb too and post the output here, if needed.

Comment: @Guilherme Franco 'qn1_path  GET|POST       /qn1(.:format)      questions#qn1' &
'submit_path  GET|POST       /submit(.:format)   questions#submit'. Arent these two enough?

Comment: They're enough. Try this:

`form_for @user, submit_path, method: :post`

And tell me if it works. If not, remove the `@user` from `form_for` and try again. It would be nice if you tell some of the output from the server logs

Comment: Its working without @user. But if answer is "blank" it is to be redirected to root path. But even if the answer is blank it is rendering 'qn1'.

Comment: If you remove @user, the `params[:user]` isn't accessible anymore. Try with `params[:answer]` directly. If it not works after this update, post the error or log output, please.

Comment: Oh, and it's not `render root_path`. It is `redirect_to root_path`

Comment: I made it redirect_to and also tried with params[:answer]. There is no error but still it is not redirecting

Comment: the action is shown as 'qn1' in the debug(params) when I click the submit button. Shouldn't it show action as submit?

Comment: Try to print whatever params[:answer] is giving you. See in the server logs (request parameters are always shown there) or raise an exception with an inspect clause: `raise params[:answer].inspect`

Comment: Request  

    Parameters:

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
       "authenticity_token"=>"+AoCq8yUHLs2aX8otlaiJi/lUxHA7d9mPkgGcLxLOI0=",
     "/submit"=>{"answer"=>"blank"},
     "commit"=>"Submit"}

Comment: OK, put back the `@user` declaration on the `form_for` and see the request parameters again. It probably will have "user" => {"answer" => "blank"}. Access the `params[:user][:answer]` in the controller and it should be done. Notice that you'll have to set `@user` in the qn1 action first

Comment: <%= form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'questions', :action => 'submit') do |f| %>  This is form_for and I am getting the error:  No route matches [PATCH] "/submit"

Comment: `<%= form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'questions', :action => 'submit', method: :post) do |f| %>`

Comment: `<%= form_for @user, url: submit_path, method: :post do |f| %>`

Comment: Very very thanks. It worked. Thank you once again for helping me throughout the whole stupid questions.

Comment: Finally !! Huzzah !! No problem at all ! It is good to help !

Comment: I am creating a website where users signup and answer questions to get to the next level. I am new to rails and so dont really  know how to implement it all. Hoping for this kind of help again :)

Comment: No problem at all. Just ask and I'll try to help !

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco Can you please take a look at this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192949/deleting-users-in-devise-generated-model)